# Lost CVV number automatically virus related?

Tags: credit-card

If my credit card was used on Amazon, doesn't that mean someone has my cvv number? And would that mean I have a virus?  Or is there another way they can get a CVV code off a credit card?  I know it's possible a site stored it when they should **NOT** have, but that's the only other way I can think of.

Comment: I believe you're referring to the CVV number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call your credit card company and ask them whether the [CVV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_security_code) number was supplied as part of that transaction.  (I don't think Amazon has ever asked for mine.)

Even if it was, that doesn't necessarily imply a virus or other malicious software on your computer.  That number could have leaked from another merchant, or even from someone to whom you presented your card in person.  That said, if you don't have anti-malware software, you should correct that *today.*

Comment: I do have anti virus,  I've been reading MSSE isn't as good as AVG, maybe I'll just do some offline scans. I am just wondering if I should re-install all 5 computers in the house.

Comment: I probably wouldn't.  I'd probably do a "full scan" of all, though.  (But someone who is more cautious than I might.  This, like almost all security questions, is a risk vs. cost question.)  *First* find out if the CVV number was even used.

Comment: All 3 I checked came back clean, 4th I'm re-installing and putting an SSD in.... I'll run a scan on the 5th later, but it's pretty crusty and rarely used anymore, plus my wife and I NEVER use it.

I'll still have to check on Amazon, but thanks for making the work more an annoyance that all 3 computers were off than me endlessly re-installing.